# Appropriate supervised learning algorithm for 200+ categorical variables predicting categorical outcome

Tags: regression, machine-learning, matlab, algorithms, supervised-learning

**CONTEXT**

I have a survey of 200+ multiple choice questions, most of which have different options (I was not the one who designed it). I have a categorical (yes/no) outcome variable. I'd like to find which of the 200+ questions' response have the most effect on these outcome variables (assume that a YES is good).

**PROBLEM**

The only workflows I've seen for this are with numerical responses. I assume that for categorical responses I will need to run a supervised learning algorithm. Since most of the choices are different, there isn't much point in converting them to numbers (unless necessary).

**QUESTION**

I've come across [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/supervised-learning-machine-learning-workflow-and-algorithms.html) but am not sure which algorithm might be best for the task. What would be a good way to decide?